# What is an appropriate method for comparing strength of predictors between two regressions on different populations?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, predictor

I have two populations of interest: Population 1 and Population 2. I have conducted the same linear regression model (outcome Y and predictors A B C) on both populations, for a total of two models. Each model results in a set of coefficients and standard errors.

I wish to compare the effect size (magnitude) of predictor A on the outcome in Population 1 to the effect size of predictor A in Population 2 and determine if there is evidence of a difference in the effect sizes, taking the variability of the coefficients into account.

What is the appropriate method or formulas to achieve this? Bonus points for any useful Stata commands that can be used to implement this method.

Comment: Just combine the two samples into one, estimate each of the two models on the combined sample by introducing dummy variables, and then run an F-test for $H_0: \beta_1 = \gamma_1$.

Comment: What does γ1 represent here? Is it the equivalent coefficient in the second population?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In my suggestion $\beta_1$ and $\gamma_1$ are the two parameters you would like to compare. I labelled them with the same number but different letters because, presumably, they correspond to the same predictor.

Comment: Thank you. I don't quite understand what the dummy variables should be. Can you explain that further?

Comment: Posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your full model, run on the combined sample, is
$$
Y_i = \beta_0 * 1_{\{i\ \in\ \text{sample}\ 1\}} + \gamma_0 * 1_{\{i\ \in\ \text{sample}\ 2\}} +
$$
$$
+
\beta_1 * X_{i1} 1_{\{i\ \in\ \text{sample}\ 1\}} + \gamma_1 * X_{i1} 1_{\{i\ \in\ \text{sample}\ 2\}} + ... + \varepsilon_i,
$$
where $\beta_1$ and $\gamma_1$ are the two coefficients of interest. Next, you run an F-test comparing the hypotheses
$$
H_0: \beta_1 = \gamma_1
$$
and
$$
H_1: \beta_1 \neq \gamma_1.
$$